# How to write shapefiles more efficiently in GeoScript?

Tags: shapefile, geoprocessing, udig, geoscript, groovy

I've created a [geoscript](http://geoscript.org/groovy/) (in groovy) to create a shapefile from generated geometries with certain attributes.

It's a heatmap consisting roughly 65.000 polygons with an attribute storing the temperature. The final code to write the shapefile looks like that:

```java
dir = new Directory("/my/path")
shp = dir.create('heatmap',
                 [
                     ["geom", "Polygon", "epsg:4326"],
                     ["temp", "float"]
                 ]
                )
// ...
temperatures.eachWithIndex{ temperature, index ->
    shp.add([geometries[index], temperature])
}
```

The last line is the issue here. Adding each of the 65k attributes to the shapefile is taking ages.

I've found out that (because shapefiles are a proprietary, binary format) adding each geometry causes the shapefile to completely be rewritten from scratch. The result is, that the efford to write records to a shapefile is not linear but exponential to the number of records.

That's a huge problem. Is there any way to write the stuff more efficiently to the shapefile? I got all geometries and all attributes stored in arrays, isn't there any way to write them all at once?

Comment: Hi qdoe, I think you were not the only one with this problem. As it seems from this discussion https://groups.google.com/d/topic/geoscript/ztA1NLW2B2Q/discussion , the library is currently being improved on that side.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the dir.add() method for implicit data conversion. You must first store your geometries and temperatures in a temporary Layer, just like you did for the Shapefile. To write to the Shapefile in one command, execute dir.add(layer). Please see this example, [data conversion](http://blog.opengeo.org/2012/12/17/hacking-with-geoscript/).